# Is there a way to access azure key vault without using AD authentication?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-keyvault

I want to access the secrets in my azure key vault using my azure credentials without using Azure AD App authentication. Is there a possible way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need the serviceprincipal name to decry-pt the key. Hence the answer is unfortunately NO.

Answer (score -2):

We can do it using Azure PowerShell script in C# code. For this we would require only the name of the keyvault, name of secret and Azure credentials of the user who wants to access it.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Program program = new Program();
            string scriptText = "Login-AzureRmAccount";
            string result = program.RunScript(scriptText);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private string RunScript(string scriptText)
    {

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();        
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("$secret = Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret -VaultName '[Name_of_keyVault]' -Name '[Name_of_secret]'");
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Write $secret.SecretValueText");
        Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();           
        runspace.Close();            
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        return stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
```

Actually, i wanted to access key vault without AD application authentication. This was the only way i could think of.

Comment: Why are you calling PS from within C# when there are packages to do this directly?  Don't need to call PS from C#.  Also arent you just logging into AAD anyway?  The question said he didnt want to do that.